# Save all general registers except ax

Tags: assembly

What is the better way to save all general-purpose registers in procedure except AX register? Maybe it can be done without USES statement?

```
InputNumberInAX proc 
    pusha ; except AX

    popa ; except AX
    ret 
endp
```

Comment: Do you know how to save one register?

Comment: yes, it's can be done with using `push AX` until popa and  after popa use `pop` to retrieve AX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using a weird ABI where you save/restore all registers except EAX, and are using PUSHA, I assume you're optimizing for code-size instead of speed.

In that case:

```
InputNumberInAX proc 
    pusha             ; this doesn't clear EAX, you don't *need* to avoid copying it to the stack
    ;; then calculate something
    ;; and store it to [esp+28]
    popa              ; loads EAX with the value we just stored.

    ret 
endp
```

[POPA pops EAX last](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPA:POPAD.html), after all the ESP adjustments.  I think the +28 displacement is right; I just did it quickly counting in my head.

Of course, if this is 16-bit code, adjust the offset as needed.

Comment: Thank. I think you right, using simple pop and push will be better.

Comment: Nitpick: For the 16-bit `PUSHA` used here I believe the correct displacement would be +14 in this case and accessed indirectly via `BP` or some other register due to the limited addressing modes. Of course the real question here is what sadist decided that the legacy 16-bit 8086 architecture was a good choice for teaching the basics of assembly language in a school environment..

Comment: @doynax : A true 8086 sadist wouldn't be using pusha/popa because that level of sadism was available only on 80186/80188 and later processors. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

These are the most obvious variations for *saving all general registers but not saving the AX register*:

1. Using individual `push`/`pop` (in the order used by the `pusha`/`popa` instructions):

   ```
   InputNumberInAX proc 
    push cx dx bx bp si di  ;No need to include the SP register!
    ...
    pop di si bp bx dx cx
    ret 
   endp
   ```
2. Using `pusha`/`popa` but substituting the last known value of the `AX` register:

   ```
   InputNumberInAX proc 
    pusha
    ...
    mov [esp+14], ax  ;AX has the value of your InputNumber
    popa
    ret 
   endp
   ```

I myself would prefer the second variation because it's both smaller in code size and more readable.

Comment: Does MASM really assemble a multi-operand PUSH into multiple separate PUSH instructions?  NASM and YASM don't allow that syntax.  Looks convenient, though.

Comment: FASM certainly allows such multi-operand `push`/`pop`.